# Metrics mismatch between BertForSequenceClassification Class and my custom Bert Classification

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I implemented my custom Bert Binary Classification Model class, by adding a classifier layer on top of Bert Model (attached below). However, the accuracy/metrics are significantly different when I train with the official BertForSequenceClassification model, which makes me wonder if I am missing somehting in my class.

Few Doubts I have:

While loading the official `BertForSequenceClassification` `from_pretrained` are the classifiers weight initialized as well from pretrained model or they are randomly initialized? Because in my custom class they are randomly initialized.

```py
class MyCustomBertClassification(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, encoder='bert-base-uncased',
                        num_labels,
                        hidden_dropout_prob):

    super(MyCustomBertClassification, self).__init__()
    self.config  = AutoConfig.from_pretrained(encoder)
    self.encoder = AutoModel.from_config(self.config)
    self.dropout = nn.Dropout(hidden_dropout_prob)
    self.classifier = nn.Linear(self.config.hidden_size, num_labels)

def forward(self, input_sent):
    outputs = self.encoder(input_ids=input_sent['input_ids'],
                          attention_mask=input_sent['attention_mask'],
                          token_type_ids=input_sent['token_type_ids'],
                          return_dict=True)
    
    pooled_output = self.dropout(outputs[1])
    # for both tasks
    logits = self.classifier(pooled_output)

    return logits
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each model tells you via a warning message which layers are randomly initialized when you use the method [from_pretrained](https://huggingface.co/transformers/main_classes/model.html#transformers.PreTrainedModel.from_pretrained):

```py
from transformers import BertForSequenceClassification

b = BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
```

Output:

```
Some weights of BertForSequenceClassification were not initialized from the model checkpoint at bert-base-uncased and are newly initialized: ['classifier.weight', 'classifier.bias']
```

The difference between your implementation and the `BertForSequenceClassification` is that you do not use any pretrained weights at all. The method [from_config](https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/auto.html?highlight=from_config#transformers.AutoModel.from_config) does not load the pretrained weights from a `state_dict`:

```py
import torch
from transformers import AutoModelForSequenceClassification, AutoConfig

b2 = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_config(AutoConfig.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased'))
b3 = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')

print("Does from_config provides pretrained weights: {}".format(torch.equal(b.bert.embeddings.word_embeddings.weight, b2.base_model.embeddings.word_embeddings.weight)))
print("Does from_pretrained provides pretrained weights: {}".format(torch.equal(b.bert.embeddings.word_embeddings.weight, b3.base_model.embeddings.word_embeddings.weight)))
```

Output:

```
Does from_config provides pretrained weights: False
Does from_pretrained provides pretrained weights: True
```

Therefore you probably want to change your class to:

```py
class MyCustomBertClassification(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, encoder='bert-base-uncased',
                       num_labels=2,
                       hidden_dropout_prob=0.1):

       super(MyCustomBertClassification, self).__init__()
       self.config  = AutoConfig.from_pretrained(encoder)
       self.encoder = AutoModel.from_pretrained(encoder)
       self.dropout = nn.Dropout(hidden_dropout_prob)
       self.classifier = nn.Linear(self.config.hidden_size, num_labels)

    def forward(self, input_sent):
       outputs = self.encoder(input_ids=input_sent['input_ids'],
                         attention_mask=input_sent['attention_mask'],
                         token_type_ids=input_sent['token_type_ids'],
                         return_dict=True)
    
       pooled_output = self.dropout(outputs[1])
       # for both tasks
       logits = self.classifier(pooled_output)

       return logits

myB = MyCustomBertClassification()

print(torch.equal(b.bert.embeddings.word_embeddings.weight, myB.encoder.embeddings.word_embeddings.weight))
```

Output:

```
True
```

Comment: yes that indeed was one of the major issue, using `from_config` instead of `from_pretrained`. However, still I see there's some performance lag with the official class which makes me wonder is there's something special going on in their initialization of the classifier network? Thoughts?

Comment: You can check the code [here](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/3552d0e0d89711404ec49b0080cd1f48ae224bb3/src/transformers/models/bert/modeling_bert.py#L616). But I am not sure if this explains the difference. @pseudo_teetotaler